# How much code is acceptable in a View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was wondering how much code is acceptable in a view ? It is acceptable to use foreach or if such if a list of items is empty.. show some message ? or should this be done in the controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a really few works

The View should containt all the code you need for your presentation logic even `ForEach` (if you need them) 
Some people like to create HTML helper to split down the presentation logic and inclapsulate it into an adhoc method

The control should be very skinny: it should just get the user interaction and delegate them to the right component. It may contain some validation logic (user input etc) but it really depends by your business requirements

Comment: you can use the foreach everywhere you need them as long as you don't break the rules above

Answer (score 0):

Rushino,

To address the specific example that you cite. For a list of items, I'd be tempted to include a strongly typed helper in the view that either returned the appropriate list OR simply returned an empty MvcString. As for other logic in the view, i'd keep it to a minimum as you quickly run out of options for unit tests once the view is littered with case statements and ifs and buts. Of course, there will be occasions where the judiciuos use of a few varables may be acceptable, but few and far between.

just my 2 cents